Node synchronization stopped
I'm trying to deploy the Sepolia RPС node, as if everything was fine, but the synchronization stopped.

Besu version 24.3.3
Configuration:
Network: Sepolia
Network Id: 11155111
Data storage: Bonsai
Sync mode: Fast
RPC HTTP APIs: ETH,NET,WEB3

The synchronization stopped at 5,186,868 blocks. Node can't find any peers to synchronize. The following message appears in the logs:
Unable to find sync target. Currently checking 0 peers for usefulness.


I changed the synchronization mode to "full" because I need the archive node, and updated the Besu to 24.5.1. Mainnet and Goerli successfully receive the peers and start synchronizing, but not Sepolia.
